# Cast from numeric to char with leading zeros in Informix

Tags: sql, database, informix

I am having problems trying to do a cast on a SQL query in Informix. I have a table with a column called `ponbr` that I am querying on. Its data type is `CHAR(8)`.

Here is my query that works fine and returns records

```
select * from xxx_shp where '02573569' = ponbr
```

However, if I type this query, it returns nothing:

```
select * from xxx_shp where to_char(02573569) = ponbr
```

This also returns nothing:

```
select * from xxx_shp where ponbr = CAST (02573569 AS char(8))
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your problem is leading zeros.  If you know that `ponbr` is a number, then do the comparison as a number:

```
where 02573569 = cast(ponbr as int)
```

Otherwise, include the leading zeros:

```
where to_char(02573569, '&&&&&&&&') = ponbr
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply check the result returned by `to_char(02573569)` and `CAST (02573569 AS char(8))`, it's probably `'2573569'`

Assuming that Informix `TO_CHAR` works similar to Oracle you need to apply a format with leading zeroes:

```
where to_char(02573569, '00000000') = ponbr
```

Comment: Correct diagnosis.  Unfortunately, Informix's TO_CHAR() isn't sufficiently like Oracle's and the `'00000000'` format generates `********` as the result (tested against Informix 12.10 on a Linux machine).  The series of `&` characters suggested by Gordon does work — somewhat to my surprise.